# Multiplication optimization

Tags: optimization

I heard, that there is a way to optimize `a * 10` operation (in any language) into something like  `a * 2 * 2 * 2 + a * 2` and get a great benefit because `*2` translates into simple binary shift operation and works much faster than multiplication operation.
Is it right?

Comment: Most modern CPUs have the same throughput for integer multiply as for any other integer ALU operation (other than division, which is a special case), so optimisations such as this are in general not appropriate unless you're working with a very old or unusual architecture.

Comment: Seems to me that a compiler that changes  `int * 2 * 2 * 2` into `int << 3` would also optimise `int * 10` if appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's true. However, a good compiler may do this automatically for you when multiplying a variable by a suitable constant (if it's appropriate for the target CPU architecture).

I just tried this with GCC on an Intel target, and `-O` didn't use the shift-and-add method. I guess the `imul` instruction is faster. However, I certainly have seen this type of code generated by GCC with an ARM target, where the multiplication instruction is relatively slow.

Comment: Actually at least for x86 there's quite a good chance that `a << 1` would be slower than add `a + a`, so yes the compiler is a) doing the right thing and b) the important take away is to really stay away from such low level optimizations and let the compiler worry about those unintuitive problems

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, the best way to optimize the code depends on the particular CPU.  However, given deep pipelining, register renaming and out of order execution supported on modern processors, it also really depends very much on the surrounding code, and what can be scheduled into the blanks.

[Check out this list of latencies and throughputs](http://gmplib.org/~tege/x86-timing.pdf).  On modern dektop processors for 4 shift and an add vs. 1 multiply:  A shift has 2x the throughput, and 1/3rd the latency (on a Nehalem or Sandybridge).  4 of them will almost certainly be a loss, even without the add.  On other processors, the situation may be different.  I say "almost", since conceivably, the multiplaction unit could be processing another chain of multiplies in nearby code, leaving the shift and add units available to do the multiply by 10 in parallel.

Always try it out yourself and measure, and of course, only do this when you really have to count clocks. :-)